# Enable/disable clipping per material (r87)

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to work with THREE's clipping planes, I didn't read the description of `Material.clipIntersection` and just blindly took it to mean "is clipping enabled".

After reading the description, playing with the example and digging through code I've concluded that there is no parameter to control wether the clipping is enabled or not. The only two interfaces are:

`.clippingPlanes[]`

`.clipIntersection`

And perhaps `Renderer.localClippingEnabled` but i don't want to globally enable/disable the... local clipping. Ie. if i have two materials, i'd like to be able to control it on one.

The problem seems to be that `clippingPlanes` defines `NUM_CLIPPING_PLANES`:

```
'#define NUM_CLIPPING_PLANES ' + parameters.numClippingPlanes,
```

And I can see that there is more stuff going on with `WebGLClipping`. Still i'm confused by the define and am wondering if i need to update the material every time i add/remove the clipping planes.

tl:dr;

Is there a built in way to easily add a toggle to enable/disable the clipping to this example:
https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_clipping_intersection, **without recompiling the shader**?

Comment: Setting `mesh.material.clippingPlanes[ 0 ].constant = BigNumber;` should have the same effect as disabling clipping.

Comment: That was another thought, do you know if this is just as fast as having an if check before the clipping logic on an uniform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not in the spirit of your question, but the easy solution is to replace the `clippingPlanes` property with an empty array.

I changed/added the following code in the example:

```
var params = {
    clipPlanesOn: true,
    clipIntersection: true,
    planeConstant: 0,
    showHelpers: false
};
```

...

```
var clipPlanes = [
    new THREE.Plane( new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 ), 0 ),
    new THREE.Plane( new THREE.Vector3( 0, - 1, 0 ), 0 ),
    new THREE.Plane( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, - 1 ), 0 )
];
var clipPlanesOff = [];
```

...

```
gui.add( params, 'clipPlanesOn' ).name( 'clip planes on' ).onChange( function ( value ) {

    var children = group.children;

    for ( var i = 0; i < children.length; i ++ ) {

        children[ i ].material.clippingPlanes = (value) ? clipPlanes : clipPlanesOff;

    }

    render();

} );
```

Checking the box turns the clipping on/off.

**Update with more info:**

AFAICT, it's all "automagic". Each render during `setProgram`, `WebGLRenderer` sets a variable called `_clippingEnabled`. This is set based on the return value from `WebGLClipping.init`, where one of the cases checks if the material has any values in its `clippingPlanes` property.

`WebGLClipping` has the following line:

```
uniform = { value: null, needsUpdate: false };
```

With `_clippingEnabled` set to `true`, and some values in the `clippingPlanes` property, the process makes its way into `projectPlanes` of `WebGLClipping`, which includes the line:

```
uniform.needsUpdate = true;
```

Boom. The uniform is flagged for automagic update.

Comment: Off the top of your head do you know how this works? Does it set `needsUpdate` somewhere automagically? This is what I meant by adding/removing from that array. It can be nullified, but I'm intimidated by the fact that it does `#define ...` in GLSL. I'm also not sure what would happen performance wise if i added a uniform and an if check by using `onBeforeCompile`, or is it better to just switch between two different versions of the material, one without clipping planes one with.